# catching a variable value at the point of adding event

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an image carousel in javascript and I'm having problem while adding event listener, the basic code to have the image indicator is something like this:

```
Array.from(mCOMPLEX_ImgTags).forEach(
        function(eachImageTag){
            // mCOMPLEX_ImgPaths.push(eachImageTag.getAttribute("src"));
            
            carouselIndicator = new COMPLEX_Img(carouselIndicatorProps, true);
            
            
            carouselIndicator = carouselIndicator.make();

            carouselIndicator.addEventListener("mouseenter", enterEvent=>{
                    CssHelper.assignStyleProp(carouselIndicator,{"background":"#ffa500"} );
                    });

            carouselIndicator.addEventListener("mouseleave", enterEvent=>{
                    CssHelper.assignStyleProp(carouselIndicator,{"background":"#ff0000"});
                    });

            mCOMPLEX_Container.appendChild(carouselIndicator);
            

        });
```

now the indicators are fine and placed allright, but, the problem is that the variable `carouselIndicator` seems to be a reference to an object, and that reference is changed as it loops in javascript(i.e. the value of the reference is not captured whilst adding the listener, which I'd expect to).   As a result, when I hover on any one of my 5 indicators, only the last one gets highlighted.

How can I save the reference that was supposed to be saved? i.e. the individual indicators have their references saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `carouselIndicator` is declared outside the scope of the closure in your `forEach()` loop, so this will only refer to a single location in memory.  Because Javascript variables are assigned/copied by reference, each time you loop through you are just updating the value at that memory location.  Meanwhile you *are* creating new event listeners, however they all point to the same thing.

Solution: declare your var inside the loop.

```js
        function(eachImageTag){
            let carouselIndicator = new COMPLEX_Img(carouselIndicatorProps, true);
//          ^^^

            ...
        }
```